# Dependent Variable Containing Multiple Binary Variables and Specifying Appropriate Model Type

Tags: r, survey, methodology

I am attempting to make a dependent variable that contains 4 survey questions that are all binary responses. I am unsure what the best way to go about doing that is potentially through a type of index.
Originally, thought a logit model would be appropriate but second-guessing since the D.V. will not be a binary variable once changed.

This is clearly a hypothetical example but identical to what I am attempting to do:

Attempting to make a group of who go to fast food chains.

D.V. would contain 4 questions:

1. Do you eat McDonalds fast food? (0 = No/ 1= Yes)
2. Do you eat Wendys fast food? (0 = No/ 1= Yes)
3. Do you eat Arbys fast food? (0 = No/ 1= Yes)
4. Do you eat Burger King fast food? (0 = No/ 1= Yes)

This would end up getting tested with different control variables that are either categorical or binary.

Thoughts?
Referred here from StackOverflow [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019431/dependent-variable-with-multiple-survey-questions).

Comment: Please provide a description of all variables involved.